# Entity Framework 6: Turn off Sequential GUIDs

Tags: guid, sequential, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6 appears to default to *sequential* GUIDs instead of completely random ones. How do I turn this off?

See CodePlex work item: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/71

Answer (score 2):

From the [changeset](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/f986cb32d0a3f56dab36be6b1ee2d810883b156d#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Sql/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs) linked to that work item, you'll see that the `GuidColumnDefault` isn't based on any settings, but just returns the default based on the provider type

Looking at this [link](http://blog.jongallant.com/2013/04/guid-comb-ef-code-first.html#.UmFhE_k8B8F), it would appear you can set it manually in your migrations though:

```
// Excerpt from migration in link above:
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Items",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false,
                    identity: true,
                    // You would use newid() instead.
                    defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()"),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);      
}
```

Comment: If this is possible in a migration, does the modelbuilder (OnModelCreating) possibly provide similar functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not very likely. This is more of a migration concern, since the model is about relationships between entities and not database type concerns. Everything on the model side needs to be generic to any potential database provider to allow you to switch to another one seamlessly. There may be other hooks that I'm unaware of, but they probably don't exist in the `ModelBuilder`.

Comment: That's really disappointing. People use non sequential GUIDs all the time because they are not guessable, no worries about key conflict issues when joining tables, etc. - this should have been at least a setting in EF6 instead of a forced change.

Comment: Sequential guide *are* globally unique as long as the generating machine has a MAC address. You should never have key conflicts. Also, non-sequential Guids ARE guessable. They're not cryptographically random.